# Javascript modularising large objects

Tags: javascript, data-structures, modularization

I've got an object defined as a function, and it's got a lot of methods and properties in it, what are some ways to modularise this to make it more manageable?  It is possible to put functions inside the object into external files?

Edit:

Someone mentioned in one answer to include other files, but this would have an unweildy HTML page, IE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script3.js"></script>
....
<script type="text/javascript" src="script76.js"></script>
```

Is there also any way to structure the code so only one reference is required the the javascript file?

Comment: You should generally try to have as few external scripts as possible.

Comment: What exactly "managing problems" do you have with your current code?

Comment: I have a object with a lot of methods in it, I would much prefer to have the functions split into seperate files into groups so they are a lot easier to manage than one huge file.

Comment: Is all the code needed on each web-page, or are you trying to split the code up into multiple files so that you can serve only the required functions to each web-page? btw, if you don't prefix your comment with "@Šime", I won't get a notification about your response. I believe "@Sime" works too in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myobj = {
  somefunc: function() { /* function code */ },
  prop: "some string",
  // etc.
};
```

and in another js file included after the above code

```
myobj.anotherfunc = function () { /* function code */ };
```

Comment: Thanks, +1, but this would require the inclusion of a lot of script references on the base HTML page right?  Anyway to design the data to avoid that issue?  Ideally it would be nice to just include one file.

Comment: @Tom No, I don't see how that would be related.

Comment: How do you include another js file from a .js file?

Comment: @Tom That issue has surely already been addressed on SO numerous times. Try searching for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). It lets you define functions, modules, dependencies and load external Javascript files from Javascript (possibly async).

Answer (score 0):

you could use a server side script to handle your javascripts, with jsmin you could even speed up the process (if cached).

i'm thinking of a script somthing like this:
    scripts.php

```
<?php 

$files = array('script1.js', 'script2.js');
$output = '';

foreach($files as $file){
    $output .= file_get_contents($file);
}

header("Content-type: application/x-javascript");
echo $output;

?>

your html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script.php"></script>
```

you could also just include all js files inside a folder, just generate the array via folder scanning or something, i think you get the idea!

greetings Nexum

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:
http://www.cryer.co.uk/resources/javascript/script17_include_js_from_js.htm

...but best practices are to just include the files you want in the main html page